# Rolling XML log file Enterprise Library 6

Tags: c#, xml, logfiles, enterprise-library-6

I have used XML log files and rolling flat files as my log destinations using respective TraceListeners in enterprise library.

I now need a rolling XML log file. Can I implementing a custom listener which creates a rolling XML log file? Can you give me some pointers on how to go about this.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648533.aspx

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I have seen this and using it to build my RollingXMLFileListener. But I was wondering if there was a way to reuse the "Rolling" behavior in EntLib.

Comment: I am not to sure you could reuse the behavior in terms of extending / inheritance. The Enterprise Library code is open source though. You could probably look at it for reference.